# connect-flash in express 4 & passport

Tags: node.js, flash, express, passport.js

I've got a really simple node website, which I am trying to use connect-flash. I cannot get the flash data to work at all

In my app I'm using this for the configuration

```
app.use(cookieParser(config.secret));
app.use(session({ secret: config.secret, name: 'sid', cookie: { secure: true }}));
app.use(flash());
```

and my login post route

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { 
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true,
        failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.'
    });
);
```

and my login get route.

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.locals.errors = req.flash();
    console.log(res.locals.errors);
    res.render('login', { 
        errors: res.locals.errors
    });
});
```

The application itself is working well and the session is being set on successful authentication. But the flash data on is never set, always an empty object. I have even tried using one route just to set the flash data and redirect and the redirect route just to console log the flash messages. But that also does the same thing.

Do I need to use a session store (mongo or redis) or should it work with the built in memory sessions?

Comment: It seems that the issue is caused by the session being created new on each page load. The data is being stored in mongoDB now. I've had a similar issue before where express.favicon() was able to fix it. However express 4 does not have this included anymore. I've used the suggested replacement, but the issue still occurs...

Comment: Unrelated, but you set `failureFlash` twice, which is meaningless.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The ordering of the middleware was the issue.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: If it _was_ the middleware order then it was something other than what you listed, as the middleware order stated in your question is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually seem like a middleware issue to me. Are you sure that flash messages are stored before you're trying to retrieve them?

Try doing something like `req.flash('info', 'Flash is back!')` Then writing it out via `console.log(req.flash('info'))`